# How to access constant char* array with asterix in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
    char* strings_array[100];

    strings_array[0] = (char*)"anisha";
    strings_array[1] = (char*)"kaul";
    strings_array[2] = (char*)"shizuka";
    strings_array[3] = (char*)"sharma";


    // Access the first character of 3rd string.
    std::cout << "\n" << *strings_array[2];

    // Access the second character of 3rd string.
    std::cout << "\n" << strings_array[2][1];
```

What is the way to access remaining characters of 3rd string by using asterix as I have accessed the first character?

`std::cout << "\n" << *strings_array[2];`

Comment: what do you mean by `access`? do you just want to print the 3rd string omitting the first character?

Comment: how to improve the question. Why downvote, please explain.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Like I have printed the first character, similarily I want to print the second character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't cast away constness! Add `const`:

```
char const * strings_array[100];
     ^^^^^
```

Any attempt to modify these strings will result in Undefined Behaviour.

As of the access:

```
std::cout << strings_array[index_string][index_character];
// equivalent to:
std::cout << *(strings_array[index_string] + index_character);
```

Which gives<sup>(*)</sup> for the first character (`index_character` = 0):

```
std::cout << *strings_array[index_string]);
```

<sup>(*)</sup> `[]` has higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `*`.

Answer (score 2):

To access an element in an array (through a pointer) without `[]`s, you can increment the pointer and then dereference it.

```
// these are equivalent
strings_array[2][1];
*(strings_array[2] + 1);
```